# How to manage python memory?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, list-comprehension, brute-force

I created a brute force program using python3 and i always get an MemoryError during the process. At the beginning the user has to put in a hash algorithm (all possible algorithms are given), then the user has to choose a chars pattern and give the minimum and maximum possible password lengths. Then the code uses the choosen chars pattern and tries any possible combination, hashs that with the choosen algorithm and compare the hash with the given hash from the user. If they are equal, the code give out the password which got combined using the pattern. The problem is, that my code crashes at the execution at the password lenght of 5.

Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ashka/PycharmProjects/bruteforce/main.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/ashka/PycharmProjects/bruteforce/main.py", line 116, in main
    bruteforce(min, max, hash, hashfunction)
  File "C:/Users/ashka/PycharmProjects/bruteforce/main.py", line 91, in bruteforce
    if bf_sha512(_, hash) is not None:
  File "C:/Users/ashka/PycharmProjects/bruteforce/main.py", line 23, in bf_sha512
    passwords = [functools.reduce(operator.add, (p)) for p in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n)]
  File "C:/Users/ashka/PycharmProjects/bruteforce/main.py", line 23, in <listcomp>
    passwords = [functools.reduce(operator.add, (p)) for p in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n)]
MemoryError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The coderegion where the error appears:

```
def bf_sha512(n, hash, chars):
    print(' ')
    print('Testing all possible passwords with ' + str(n) + ' characters... [' + str(int(chars.__len__())**n) + ']')
    time.sleep(1)
    with tqdm(total=int(chars.__len__())**n) as pbar:
        count = 0
        for password in [functools.reduce(operator.add, p) for p in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n)]:
            count += 1
            pbar.update(1)
            if hashlib.sha512(password.encode()).hexdigest() == hash:
                print('Needed attempts: ' + str(count))
                print(' ')
                print("Hash: " + hash)
                print("Passwort: " + password)
                pbar.close()
                return password
        pbar.close()
        return None
```

I even tried to remove all cosmetic lines like the progressbar and the counting, but it crashed anyway.

Comment: that list is going to be huge... you need to iterate over the result from itertools.product without creating the other list

Comment: You don’t need to ‘manage’ Python memory, but you do need to not attempt to take all of the available OS memory with the data your code tries to create in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem in the line that causes this error is the transformation from a generator (a piece of code that yields one result at a time until it finishes running) that is very memory-efficient, to a list by using `[]` around `functools.reduce(operator.add, p) for p in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n)`.

by converting it into a list you make the generator output all its values into a list, which cannot contain more than 536,870,912 items on 32bit machines. when the list gets bigger than that you get the memory error.

solution: remove the `[]`